# How to use more advanced parameters on Doctrine query builder's 'orderBy()'?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use natural sorting on MySQL through doctrine's query builder. But the orderBy() function doesn't have the parameters I need.

This is the query I need to pass to doctrine:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `ouvidoria`
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(`id`, LENGTH(`id`)-3) AS UNSIGNED) DESC;
```

I have tried the following:

```php
public function getLastKeyOfOrigin($origin) {
    $data = $this->getRepository()->findOneBy(['origin'=>$origin->getId()]);
    $select = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $select->select('o')
           ->from($this->entityPath, 'o')
           ->where("o.origin = :origin")
           ->setParameter('origin', $origin)
           ->orderBy('CAST(RIGHT(o.id, LENGTH(o.id)-3) AS UNSIGNED)', 'DESC')
           ->setMaxResults('1');
     return $select->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

which gives the following error:

> Type: Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
> Message: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 79: Error: Expected known function, got 'CAST'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by ordering the query by 2 columns, but answering the asked question you can use doctrine's NativeQuery class to send naked SQL through doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```php
$select->select('o')
           ->from($this->entityPath, 'o')
           ->where("o.origin = :origin")
           ->setParameter('origin', $origin)
           ->addSelect('CAST(RIGHT(o.id, LENGTH(o.id)-3) AS UNSIGNED) AS HIDDEN orderCol')
           ->orderBy('orderCol', 'DESC')
           ->setMaxResults('1');
```

So, you keep `orderBy()` simple by using alias defined elsewhere, and this helps you to overcome its limitations.

Comment: thanks for the answer but that still gives the same error.

Comment: Oh, I see now, the problem was not in complexity of the expression, but rather in usage of SQL functions which are not re-defined as DQL functions. Yep, in this case  my advice is just unrelated. I think your best bet would be using a native query, i.e. make it in plain SQL (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html). Or, you could implement these missing functions (or make a new one which does what you want), but I guess this is just an overkill.

Comment: Too bad Doctrine (AFAIK) does not allow to just inject SQL snippet into QueryBuilder, unlike e.g. Eloquent from Laravel. I guess that would break some strong abstractions in Doctrine.

Comment: I'll probably end up going for the overkill, rebuilding the whole system to use native query would be even worse. :/

Comment: This one query does not seem too bad, I mean you can use native query right here, without any changes in any other palce. Why would you need to rebuild whole system?

Comment: Ah, and obligatory comment: you seem to have two related yet different values in the same column. This is not a properly normalized data. You should have two columns instead (maybe 3 if you need both values combined, but virtual column would be better in this case.) But this would be "rebuilding whole system", yes.